# Passing Extra context to ListViews in Django

Tags: django, django-views, django-context

Can anyone please tell me how I can pass the "query" on my ListView as a context while at the same time keeping "search_results" as a context_object_name? I just can't get my head around it:

```
class SearchResulView(ListView):
    model = Product
    template_name = 'shop/product/search_results.html'
    context_object_name = 'search_results' 

    def get_queryset(self):
        query = self.request.GET.get("q")
        search_results = Product.objects.filter(
            Q(name__icontains=query)
            )
        return search_results
```

Am trying to render the values passed to "query" on my template but I just can't figure out how...

Answer (score 1):

You can pass this by overriding the [**`.get_context_data(…)`** method <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-multiple-object/#django.views.generic.list.MultipleObjectMixin.get_context_data):

```
class SearchResulView(ListView):
    model = Product
    template_name = 'shop/product/search_results.html'
    context_object_name = 'search_results' 

    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().filter(
            name__icontains=self.request.GET.get('q')
        )

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context['query'] = self.request.GET.get('q')
        return context
```

You however do not need to override the `.get_context_data(…)` method. In the template you can access this with:

```
{{ view.request.GET.q }}
```